If an enum declared in a namespace is defined outside the namespace, are its enumeration values externally visible?
I think scoped enumerations are too restrictive so I have always used this method, but I found out today that it cause naming pollution in CLANG. What does the standard say about visibility?
namespace E1_space {
    enum E1: int;
}
using E1 = E1_space::E1;  // or using E1_space::E1;
enum E1_space::E1: int {
    Error
};

void foo() {
    Error; 
    // x86-64 GCC 14.2 error: 'Error' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'P3::E1_space::Error'?
    // x64 MSVC v19.latest error C2065: 'Error': undeclared identifier
    // x86-64 CLANG 19.1.0 warning: expression result unused
}


Please [edit] your question to copy-paste (as text) the actual errors you get.

OT: Please note that using E1 = E1_space::E1; does something very different from using E1_space::E1;. They might seem to do the same thing, but are semantically not the same at all.

@Someprogrammerdude I know they don't have the same semantics, but the representation is the same in this use case

@Someprogrammerdude I was actually hoping for an error, which I thought should have been obvious, but CLANG passed instead, which gave me a headache

If an enum declared in a namespace is defined outside the namespace, are its enumeration values externally visible? No.  You may want to consider filing a bug with the clang folks.  If you are looking for chapter-and-verse in the C++ standard, consider adding the language-lawyer tag.

@Eljay Ah, for me I just want to focus on what the standards are, I'm not particularly concerned about the compiler. Since I'm generally not involved in the discussion, I don't even know where to submit these bugs.

Either with or without using, Clang behaves the same and disagrees with the other two.

"too restrictive" is a personal opinion.  Using enum class is a good thing since it avoids name clashes. Try to use the language as it is intended, or you will surprise other readers of your code. (e.g. us)

@PepijnKramer Since my programming scenario often requires the use of and/or logic for enumerations, unscoped enumerations that are namespace-restricted are more applicable to me. But there was something wrong with this macro in clang, so I expanded it and questioned it. This is beside the point.

Read this : How to use enums as flags in C++. Your logic can/should be implemented as a function that takes the type of your enum. (On a fundamental level I agree since bitwise operators can yield values that are NOT part of the enum and thus breaks the enum... but it seems that is opinion based). Note : I add this comment not specifically for you but other readers of this question.

Also noteworthy is that unscoped enums can very easily generate UB that isn't widely understood (e.g. underlying type int doesn't mean all int values are valid, and casts can give you UB).

@PepijnKramer In principle, it is possible to overload the operator once and for all, but to me it requires too many operations to overload , and it is also contagious.It is more to my taste to specify that an enumeration can be operated

@JeffGarrett This is the difference between typed and untyped enumerations, not between scoped and unscoped enumerations.

Yes, it is between enums with fixed underlying type and those without. But scoped enums always have fixed underlying type. The problem enums are unscoped enums without the type specified, making the ": int" a very crucial and subtle difference between a valid program and not.

This is how I would declare bitwise operations on a scoped enum : https://godbolt.org/z/vbT6jaz7a.  I chose the result to be of underlying type, but it is easily changed to the scoped enum type (even if the values would not be enum values themselves)

@PepijnKramer Thank you. It's really worth learning for me.

You're welcome.  The main thing is that with templates you don't have to write the same functions over and over again for each enum and you can still use scoped enums

It would seem the language itself (as of C++23 at least) has a bug, which makes Clang's behavior technically legal (regardless of using being present or not).

[dcl.enum]
12 The name of each unscoped enumerator is also bound in the scope that immediately contains the enum-specifier.

Now, you define an unscoped enumeration and the global scope does seem to "immediately contain the enum-specifer". That is because enum-specifier is the whole enum definiton:

 enum-specifier:
     enum-head { enumerator-listopt }
     enum-head { enumerator-list , } 

However, I find this totally bonkers. And while I couldn't find an issue about this with C++ Core Working Group, I don't believe that's an intended behavior.
On the LLVM bug tracker, Richard Smith (a committee member and Clang maintainer) seems to agree as well that all compilers but Clang do the sensible thing, and both Clang as well as the language itself might need an amendment.

After some thinking, this is likely leftover wording from pre-C++11. You couldn't forward-declare enumerations once; only enums with a fixed underlying type can be forward-declared, and that is only since C++11. So in C++03, you can't seperate definition from first declaration, making the above wording at [dcl.enum]/12 suffice.

The answer was hilarious to me.HAHAHAHAHAHA

Please file an issue at https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues . You don't need to provide a proposed resolution, but you can if you want to.
